# Make several figures from a dictionary without overwriting the previous figure

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a 5 element dictionary named `total_shortfall_per_replicate`.  Each element is a list of length 22.

I would like to cycle through each key/value pair in the dictionary and make a figure.  I have tried the following code, but all the pairs are on the same figure instead of separate figures.

I also tried initialising `range(len(total_shortfall_per_replicate)` number of figures outside of the loop, but then I just get five figures of the final element anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def shortfall_bar(k, v, time):
    fig = plt.bar(time, v, label=k)    
    tl = 'Number of wells reporting a demand shortfall %s' %(k)
    plt.title(tl)
    plt.xlabel('Time (days)')
    plt.ylabel('Number of failed wells')
    plt.plot([0., len(time)], [22, 22], "k--")
    plt.ylim(0,25)
    plt.xlim(0,len(time))
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1, box.width, 
    box.height * 0.9])        
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0., -0.05, 1., 0.),
          borderaxespad=0, ncol= 5, numpoints=1, mode='expand') 
    plt.show()
    return fig


keys = total_shortfall_per_replicate.keys()
print keys

fig = plt.figure()        
for k in keys:
    shortfall_list = total_shortfall_per_replicate[k]
    print shortfall_list        
    my_fig = shortfall_bar(k, v=shortfall_list, time= s_d_time_list)
```

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new figure. Also see [the example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_figs_demo.html) on the matplotlib page.